# Translate multi-command pipeline bash to python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

This is what I have in my bash script:

`example=$(echo $var | cut -c 40- | sed "/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/!d")`. I am trying to translate it to python.

In Python, `echo $var | cut -c 40-` would give `print(var[40])`.

And I know that [a-zA-Z0-9] means any character in the range a-z, A-Z or 0-9. So does `sed "/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/!d"`delete every row that starts with [a-zA-Z0-9]?

Comment: Are you going to ask for all the commands ? You already posted a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74991215/6213883. You probably got the sed command from somewhere, test it and check what it does. Then translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `d` command in `sed` deletes any line which matches the address expression anywhere on the line. However, the regular expression in this case is anchored to the *end* of the line, by way of the `$` anchor. So it deletes lines whose last character is one matched by the character class (any character in the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`).

Idiomatically, a better articulation of the `cut` would be to refactor it into the `sed` script; you generally want to minimize the number of subprocesses you create.

```
import re

example = "\n".join(line[40:] for line in var.splitlines()
    if len(line) > 40 and re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]$', line))
```

You could avoid the regular expression by switching to `line.endswith(...)` but the `...` will be quite a bit more verbose than this simple regex.

The proper way to print a variable includes quoting it: `echo "$var"`. I am guessing the omission of the quotes is a mistake, and not intentional. In particular, if `var` contains multiple lines of text, the absence of quotes forces it all to be printed on a single line. There are other issues, too. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

If the variable genuinely only contains one line of text, of course, you can avoid the `splitlines()` and the loop, and simply examine the variable directly.

The command substitution will trim any trailing newlines from the result, so the lack of a final newline in `example` is not a bug here. Still, if you want to print it to a text file, you'll want to add the final missing newline.